# Is it possible to have two DataTables with the same name in XML?

Tags: c#, xml, datatable

I would like to have two `datatables` called `bndbox` to display 2 sets of coordinates as shown in the code above. But I got an error because `bndbox` already existed. I then created `object` in hopes to be able to hold `bndbox` with `object1` and `object2` but this did not work. Is there any way to get two `datatables` with the same name in a `dataset`? Or is this not possible? The ideal output would be this:

```
<annotation>
    <folder>Kangaroo</folder>
    <filename>00151.jpg</filename>
    <size>
        <width>503</width>
        <height>488</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <object>
        <bndbox>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <xmin>209</xmin>
            <ymin>186</ymin>
            <xmax>294</xmax>
            <ymax>217</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <bndbox>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <xmin>301</xmin>
            <ymin>163</ymin>
            <xmax>348</xmax>
            <ymax>178</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

Comment: you want to serialize a datatable to an XML? is that what you want? In the beginning of your question you mention "code above", but you forgot to paste your code. Have you tried holding the "object" or "bndbox" in a list - e.g. List<bndbox> bndboxes (or something to that effect). Your question needs to be more precise.

Comment: The DataSet Read/Write Xml only works with simple XML structures.  You have a complex xml file so you should not be using the DataSet method.  Instead use one of the other Xml libraries in Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only one bndbox with multiple rows.  Try the Xml Linq code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("BndBox");
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("xmin", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("ymin", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("xmax", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("ymax", typeof(int));

            foreach (XElement bndbox in doc.Descendants("bndbox"))
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    (int)bndbox.Element("ID"),
                    (int)bndbox.Element("xmin"),
                    (int)bndbox.Element("ymin"),
                    (int)bndbox.Element("xmax"),
                    (int)bndbox.Element("ymax")
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```